# Web service call failing with 5xx type errors

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

We've inherited a .asmx web service without source code (my favourite).

We've run tests (calling it from a console app with fiddler attached) both internally and externally and it runs clean every time - as it does for the vast majority of our clients.

However, one user is reporting 5xx type errors. We've tried all the usuals (event viewer and IIS logs) but they're all clean. We can't get it to fail at all.

What further options do we have?

Comment: Could the data that this 3rd party be sending in be different? Check out Failed Request Tracing on IIS http://serverfault.com/questions/90943/iis-log-request-body-post-data/90965#90965

Comment: 5xx error will show in IIS log, as IIS log will have sc-status in the log (by default I think). see the example: `#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-06-30 00:00:00 10.57.26.109 GET / - 443 - 10.57.26.226 - 200 0 0 0`

Answer (score 2):

Can the clients replicate the error at will?

The error is most likely data related.  Have you tested it with the same data that your client is to produce the error.

The error may also be at the client's end during serialization/deserialization of the call in their auto-generated asmx wrapper.

Has there been a change to the WSDL?

Things like ELMAH are great for logging all unhanded exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. add logging to web config, log everything.
2. decompile the webservice and find the reason.